# How to prepend stdout and stderr output with timestamp when redirecting into log files?

Tags: shell, logging, pipe, stdout, init

In Linux I'm starting a program called `$cmd` in an init script (SysVInit). I'm already redirecting stdout and stderr of `$cmd` into two different logfiles called `$stdout_log` and `$stderr_log`. Now I also want to add a timestamp in front of every line printed into the logfiles.

I tried to write a function called log_pipe as follows:

```sh
log_pipe() {
    while read line; do
        echo [$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S)] "$line"
    done
}
```

then pipe the output of my script into this function and after that redirect them to the logfiles as follows:

```sh
$cmd | log_pipe >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
```

What I get is an empty `$stdout.log` (stdout) what should be okay, because the `$cmd`  normally doesn't print anything. And a `$stderr.log` file with only timestamps but without error texts.

Where is my faulty reasoning?

PS: Because the problem exists within an init script I only want to use basic shell commands and no extra packages.

Comment: Did you consider the 'ts' command at all?

Candidly speaking, there's no need for the log_pipe() program as unix/linux already has the 'ts' command which does exactly what you're trying to do.

do 
"
$ man ts
"
to see if that satisfies you.

e.g usage: "$ cmd 2>&1 | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z]' | tee /your-path/outputs.log  > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any POSIX shell, try:

```
{ cmd | log_pipe >>stdout.log; } 2>&1 | log_pipe >>stderr.log
```

Also, if you have GNU awk (sometimes called `gawk`), then `log_pipe` can be made simpler and faster:

```
log_pipe() {  awk '{print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"),$0}'; }
```

#### Example

As an example, let's create the command `cmd`:

```
cmd() { echo "This is out"; echo "This is err">&2; }
```

Now, let's run our command and look at the output files:

```
$ { cmd | log_pipe >>stdout.log; } 2>&1 | log_pipe >>stderr.log
$ cat stdout.log
[2019-07-04 23:42:20] This is out
$ cat stderr.log
[2019-07-04 23:42:20] This is err
```

#### The problem

```
cmd | log_pipe >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log"
```

The above redirects stdout from `cmd` to `log_pipe`.  The stdout of `log_pipe` is redirected to `$stdout_log` and the stderr of `log_pipe` is redirected to `$stderr_log`.  **The problem is that the stderr of `cmd` is never redirected.  It goes straight to the terminal.**

As an example, consider this `cmd`:

```
cmd() { echo "This is out"; echo "This is err">&2; }
```

Now, let's run the command:

```
$ cmd | log_pipe >>stdout.log 2>>stderr.log
This is err
```

We can see that `This is err` is not sent to the file stderr.log.  Instead, it appears on the terminal.  It is never seen by `log_pipe`.  `stderr.log` only captures error messages from `log_pipe`.

Comment: This works, but my command has to run in background because it is within an init script, therefore i have to do:

```bash
({ cmd | log_pipe >>stdout.log; } 2>&1 | log_pipe >>stderr.log) &
echo $! > "$pid_file"
```

right?

But I think in this case the pid in the $pid_file is not the pid of $cmd...

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Try `({ cmd | log_pipe >>stdout.log; } 2>&1 | log_pipe >>stderr.log) & pgrep cmd > "$pid_file"`.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, you can also redirect to a subshell using process substitution:

**logger.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
   echo "[$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S)] $line"
done
```

**redirection**

```
cmd > >(logger.sh > stdout.log) 2> >(logger.sh > stderr.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but my command has to run in background because it is within an init script, therefore i have to do:

```sh
({ cmd | log_pipe >>stdout.log; } 2>&1 | log_pipe >>stderr.log) &
echo $! > "$pid_file"
```

right?

But I think in this case the pid in the $pid_file is not the pid of $cmd...

Answer (score 0):

This was the easiest way for me to accomplish this with timestamp included :

```
{ ./script.sh | ts >>script-stdout.log; } 2>&1 | ts >>script-stderr.log
```